# Script test for cell/range editable focus

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi when you double click on a Google sheets cell it goes into an editable/focus status. Is there a way to programmatically test a worksheet for a cell with this status before running a script? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try with

```
sheet.getActiveCell();
```

Comment: Oh dear is that all it is? Thanks

Comment: is it what you are looking for ..?  if yes accept it as answer so that we can save some time from others , working on it